# `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` when converting to String

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm attempting to add the result of a socket data payload to a String array :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.topAnchor),
        self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.bottomAnchor),
        self.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.leadingAnchor),
        self.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.trailingAnchor),
        ])
    self.tableView = tableView

    self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "UITableViewCell")

    self.tableView.dataSource = self

    let socket = manager.defaultSocket

    socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in
        print("socket connected")
        self.refresh()
    }

    socket.on("request") {data, ack in

        print("data is" , data[0])
        self.items.append(String(data[0] as! String))
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
```

The data payload is being received as the line

```
print("data is" , data[0])
```

prints to console :

```
data is (
    "this is a test message"
)
```

But I'm unsure how to extract the String text from `data`. 
The line `self.items.append(String(data[0] as! String))`

Returns error :

```
Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
```

Also using

```
self.items.append(data[0])
```

returns compiler error :

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Any' to expected argument type 'String'
```

How to add to the `items` array and prevent `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` and/or what is the correct method of converting `data[0]` to String ?

If I hard-code a String and add it to the array :

```
self.items.append("Test")
```

The item is added without error.

Comment: @Augusto 1. What's the purpose of casting anything to `Any`? 2. Since when does `String` have an initializer that takes `Any` as parameter? 3. Any particular reason to perpetuate the bad practice of force unwrapping?

Comment: 1,3. `Cannot convert value of type 'Any' to expected argument type 'String'`. It sounds to me that the real type is `Any`. 2. If `data[0]` is `Any`, `data[0] as! String` not works. The problem isn't initializer, and yes, force unwrap is a bad practice, but this is a little tip to know where are the problem.

Comment: @Augusto 1. `Any` already is `Any` 2. This will not compile 3. Read about optionals in Swift and stop using force unwrapping

Comment: @mag_zbc thank you, it's really not compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From console print `data[0]` is an array of strings so You can try

```
if let arr  = data.first as? [String] , let item = arr.first {
  print("data is" ,item)
  self.items.append(item)
}
```

the above code appends the first item , it's up to you to append the whole array with

```
self.items += arr
```

Comment: how you know that `data[0]` is array?

Comment: jsonObject that originally an array appears with `()` in console

Comment: But, this: `let arr = [1,4,6]; print(arr)` prints on console: `[1, 4, 6]`. No `()` is printed.

Comment: yes , but it's not the op' s case try this `let str = """ ["ssss"]
  """ ; print(try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data(str.utf8)))` output will be different if you add `as! [String]`  to the trailing of the print

Comment: `error: multi-line string literal content must begin on a new line
let str = """ ["ssss"] """`

Comment: click `fix it` helper

Comment: I'm using online playground (no mac now)

Answer (score 2):

It seems the `data` is `[[String]]`, a nested array.

Unwrap and index the stuff safely

```
    print("data is" , data[0])
    guard let innerArray = data.first as? [String],
          let string = innerArray.first else { return }
    self.items.append(string)
```

Or if you want to append all items

```
    guard let innerArray = data.first as? [String] else { return }
    self.items.append(contentsOf: innerArray)
```